# Integrate $\int_0^1 \Bigl(\mathrm{Li}_2\bigl(\frac{x-1}{x}\bigr)\Bigr)^2 \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: special-functions, definite-integrals, conjectures

This question has some relationship to [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334962/int-01-mathrmd-u-1-cdots-int-01-mathrmd-u-n-frac-delta1-u-1-cdots): Let $\mathrm{Li}_2$ be the dilogarithm. Then, numerically,
$$
  \int_0^1 \Bigl(\mathrm{Li}_2\bigl(\frac{x-1}{x}\bigr)\Bigr)^2 \mathrm{d}x
  =
  \frac{17}{180}\pi^4,
$$
as can be checked by Mathematica code like

```
NIntegrate[ PolyLog[2, (x-1)/x]^2, {x,0,1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

and

```
N[ 17/180 * Pi^4, 100]
```

both of which output the same digits

```
9.199747486544674627886031420599927173585383 ...
```

Is this a known identity? Some related results appear in [Freitas](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-251/S0025-5718-05-01747-3/S0025-5718-05-01747-3.pdf) and [Laurenzi](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6229v5.pdf), but without this specific argument in the dilogarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this follows from Freitas' paper. In Table 3 there

$$\int_0^1 \mathrm{Li}_2^2(x) \mathrm{d}x = 6 - 2\zeta(2) - 4\zeta(3) + \frac{5}{2}\zeta(4),$$
and Formula (2.2.5) of [Table of integrals and formulae for Feynman diagram calculations](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~dduke/devoto-duke-84.pdf) states
$$\mathrm{Li}_2\Bigl(-\frac{y}{1-y}\Bigr) = - \mathrm{Li}_2(y) - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1-y),$$
and Mathematica can solve
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \ln^4(1-x)\mathrm{d}x = 6
$$
as well as
$$
\int_0^1 \mathrm{Li}_2(x) \ln^2(1-x) \mathrm{d}x
=
\frac{1}{15} \left(60 (\zeta (3)-3)+5 \pi ^2+\pi ^4\right)
$$

Using these formulae, the claim follows.

Comment: Impressive! I wanted to come back to this integral later, and I probably will - as the cancellation of $\zeta(3)$ hints that there should be also an elementary derivation. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Use dilogarithm properties [(4)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) to expand the integral

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x^{-1})=-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2x$$
$$I=\int_0^1\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2x\right)^2dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\ln^4x\space dx+\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)dx+\int_0^1\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)dx$$
$$=6+J+K$$
The first integral has an elementary antiderivative, so I won't discuss it. We can evaluate the second integral with integration by parts.
$$u=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x), \space du=\frac{\ln x}{1-x}$$
$$dv=\ln^2 x,\space v=x\ln^2 x-2x\ln x+2x$$
$$J=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)(x\ln^2 x-2x\ln x+2x)\Bigg\rvert_{x→0}^{x→1}-\int_0^1(x\ln^2 x-2x\ln x+2x)\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx$$$$=-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3x}{1-x}dx+2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2x}{1-x}dx-2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{1-x}dx$$
These integrals can be evaluated easily
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \ln x}{1-x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln x\space dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}=1-\zeta(2)$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \ln^2 x}{1-x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln^2 x\space dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(n+2)^3}=2\zeta(3)-2$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \ln^3 x}{1-x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln^3 x\space dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{6}{(n+2)^4}=6-6\zeta(4)$$
$$J=-12+2\zeta(2)+4\zeta(3)+6\zeta(4)$$
We can evaluate $K$ with roughly the same method
$$u=\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x),\space du=-\frac{2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-x)}{x}$$
$$dv=dx,\space v=x$$
$$K=x\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)\big\rvert_{x=0}^{x=1}+2\int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-x)dx=\frac{\pi^4}{36}+2\int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\ln(x)dx$$
Apply integration by parts again
$$u=2\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x), \space du=\frac{2\ln x}{1-x}$$
$$dv=\ln x\space dx,v=x\ln x-x$$
$$K=\frac{\pi^4}{36}-2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2x-x\ln x}{1-x}dx=\frac{\pi^4}{36}-2(2\zeta(3)-2-1+\zeta(2))=\frac{5}{2}\zeta(4)-4\zeta(3)-2\zeta(2)+6$$

Finally,
$$I=6+J+K=\frac{17}{2}\zeta(4)=\frac{17\pi^4}{180}$$
$$I=\int_0^1\operatorname{Li}_2^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\frac{17\pi^4}{180}$$