# Generalization of Dirichlet integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is it correct that
$$\lim_{L\to\infty} \int_0^L d x \int_0^L dy \int_0^L d z \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}\frac{\sin(y+z)}{y+z}\frac{\sin(z+x)}{z+x} =\frac {\pi^3}{16}. $$
or does anybody has a reference for this? The value $\frac{\pi^3}{16}$ comes from numerics. 
The identity
$$ \lim_{L\to\infty}\int_0^L \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac \pi 2 $$
(which is sometimes also called Dirichlet integral) is well known and there are many ways to prove it. However, I need the slight generalization of this above.

Comment: Very interesting. I would expect some symmetry arguments here and possible generalizations to more variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=3$. For $1\le p\le\infty$, define $\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\st}{;\,}B_p := \set{x\in(0,\infty)^n\st \abs{x}_p \le 1}$, which is the intersection of the unit $p$-ball with $(0,\infty)^n$. For $L > 0$, define
$$
\newcommand{\upd}{\mathrm{d}}
\let\underdot\d
\renewcommand{\d}{\upd} 
I_p(L) := \int_{L\cdot B_p}\d(x,y,z) \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}\frac{\sin(y+z)}{y+z}\frac{\sin(z+x)}{z+x}
=: \int_{L\cdot B_p}\d(x,y,z) f(x,y,z).
$$
The question asks about $\lim_{L\to\infty} I_\infty(L)$, integrating on the box $L\cdot B_\infty$. The answer from Yuriy S shows  $\lim_{L\to\infty} I_2(L) = \pi^3/16$, which integrates on the Euclidean sphere $L\cdot B_2$. This answer will show:

1. For all $1\le p\le\infty$, the limit $\lim_{L\to\infty} I_p(L)$ exists.
2. That limit is the same for all $p$, namely $\forall p\in[1,\infty] : \lim_{L\to\infty} I_p(L) = \lim_{L\to\infty} I_\infty(L)$.
3. On the simplex $L\cdot B_1$ we have $\lim_{L\to\infty} I_1(L) = \pi^3/16$.

The ingredients will be: The [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula), [Dichlet's test for improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), and [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Final_Value_Theorem_for_improperly_integrable_functions_(Abel%27s_theorem_for_integrals)) [versions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216837/alternative-version-of-the-final-value-theorem-for-laplace-transform) of Abel's theorem for integrals aka the [final value theorem for the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem). Only 3. needs $n=3$, the first two statements remain valid in higher odd dimensions.

#### 1. $\displaystyle\lim_{L\to\infty} I_p(L)$ exists

The coarea formula implies that for an integrable function $\varphi : (0,\infty)^n\to\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int_{L\cdot B_p}\d x \,\varphi(x) = \int_0^L\d r \int_{\abs{\xi}_p = 1} \d S_p(\xi)\, r^{n-1} \varphi(r\xi)
$$
where $\d S_p$ stands for integration with respect to a surface measure normalized by a constant (from the gradient of $\abs{\,\cdot\,}_p$). Define $f_p : (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ via
$$
f_p(r) := \int_{\abs{\xi}_p = 1} \d S_p(\xi)\, r^{n-1} f(r\xi).
$$
The existence of $\lim_{L\to\infty} \int_0^L\d r\,f_p(r)$ follows from Dirichlet's test for improper integrals
since $r \mapsto f_p(r) = r^{n-1} \int_{\abs{\xi}_p = 1} \d S(\xi)\, f(r\xi)$ factorizes into $1/r$ times a function whose integral is uniformly bounded over all intervals, since for each $\xi$ the integrand is $1/r$ times a periodic function with Cesàro mean zero.

#### 2. $\displaystyle\lim_{L\to\infty} I_p(L) = \lim_{L\to\infty} I_\infty(L)$ for all $1\le p \le \infty$

Applying the coarea formula, we want to show
\begin{equation} \tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\int_0^\infty\d r\, f_p(r)
=
\int_0^\infty\d r\, f_\infty(r).
\end{equation}
Note that both integrals exist as improper Riemann integrals, and that via Abel's theorem for integrals aka the final value theorem for the Laplace transform,
$$
    \int_0^\infty\d r\, (f_\infty(r) - f_p(r)) = \lim_{s\downarrow 0} \int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr}(f_\infty(r) - f_p(r)) 
    = \lim_{s\downarrow 0} \int_{(0, \infty)^n}\d x\, (e^{-s\abs{x}_\infty} - e^{-s\abs{x}_p}) f(x),
$$
where the last equation is a consequence of the coarea formula.
Let $s > 0$. By the mean value theorem, there is a function $0\le \alpha(x/\abs{x}_\infty) \le \abs{x}_p - \abs{x}_\infty$, such that
$$
  e^{-s\abs{x}_\infty} - e^{-s\abs{x}_p}
  =
  s(\abs{x}_p - \abs{x}_\infty)e^{-s\abs{x}_\infty(1+\alpha(x/\abs{x}_\infty))}.
$$
Applying the coarea formula yields
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr}(f_\infty(r) - f_p(r)) 
    & = s \int_0^\infty\d r\int_{\abs{\xi}_\infty = 1} \d S_\infty(\xi)\, r^n (\abs{\xi}_p - 1) e^{-sr(1+\alpha(\xi))} f(r\xi) \\
    & = \int_{\abs{\xi}_\infty = 1} \d S_\infty(\xi)\, (\abs{\xi}_p - 1) s \int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr(1+\alpha(\xi))} r^n f(r\xi) \\
    & = \int_{\abs{\xi}_\infty = 1} \d S_\infty(\xi)\, \frac{\abs{\xi}_p - 1}{(1 + \alpha(\xi))^{n+1}} s \int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr} r^n f(\tfrac{r}{1+\alpha(\xi)}\xi).
\end{align*}
For fixed $x\in(0,\infty)^n$, the function $r\mapsto f(rx)$ factors into its decay component $r^{-n}$ times a function with uniform bounded integral on all intervals, and therefore Cesàro mean zero.
The inner integral is $s$ times the Laplace transform at $s$ of that function $r\mapsto r^n f(rx)$. By a [version of the final value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216837/alternative-version-of-the-final-value-theorem-for-laplace-transform),
this converges to the Cesàro mean for $s\to 0$, which shows \eqref{eq:2}.

#### 3. $\displaystyle\lim_{L\to\infty} I_1(L) = \frac{\pi^3}{16}$

We have shown this limit exists. To actually compute it, we make again use of the [Abelian theorem for the Laplace transform, sometimes called final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem#Final_Value_Theorem_for_improperly_integrable_functions_(Abel%27s_theorem_for_integrals)),
which implies
$$
 \lim_{L\to\infty}\int_0^L\d r\, f_1(r)
=
\lim_{s\downarrow 0} \int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr} f_1(r).
$$
Let $s > 0$. We use the $\delta$ notation
$$
\int_{\Omega} \mathrm{d} \xi \delta(r-g(\xi)) \varphi(\xi):=\int_{\set{x \in \Omega\st g(x)=r}} \frac{\d S(\xi)}{|\operatorname{grad} g(\xi)|} \varphi(\xi).
$$

Then,
\begin{multline*}
\int_0^\infty\d r\, e^{-sr} f_1(r) = \int_0^\infty \d r\, e^{-sr} r^{n-1} \int_{[0,1]^{n}} \d(x, y, z)\, \delta(1-x-y-z) f(rx, ry, rz) % \frac{\sin (r(x+y)) \sin (r(y+z)) \sin (r(z+x))}{r^{3}(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}
\\
 =\int_0^\infty \d r\, e^{-sr} r^{n-1} \int_{[0,1]^{n}} \d(x, y, z)\, \delta(1-x-y-z) \tfrac{\sin (r(1-z)) \sin (r(1-x)) \sin (r(1-y))}{r^{3}(1-z)(1-x)(1-y)}
\end{multline*}
the substitution $(x, y, z) \rightsquigarrow(1-x, 1-y, 1-z)$ turns this into
$$
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \d r\, e^{-sr} r^{n-1} \int_{[0,1]^{n}}\d(x, y, z)\, \delta(x+y+z-2) \frac{\sin (r x) \sin (r y) \sin (r z)}{r^{3} x y z}
$$
and the scaling property $\delta(a x)=\delta(x) / \abs{a}$ of $\delta$ gives
$$
=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \d r\, e^{-sr} r^{n-1} \int_{[0,1]^{n}} \d(x, y, z)\, \delta\left(1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}-\frac{z}{2}\right) \frac{\sin (r x) \sin (r y) \sin (r z)}{r^{3} x y z}.
$$
Applying the coarea formula again allows us to compute the $s\to 0$ limit
$$
    =\frac{1}{2} \int_{(0, \infty)^{n}} \d(x, y, z)\, e^{-s(x+y+z)} \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin y}{y} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 
    \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(\int_0^\infty \d x\, e^{-sx} \frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr)^3 \to
    \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)^3=\frac{\pi^{3}}{16},
$$
where the convergence is a well known result which follows from the convergence of the Dirichlet integral via Dirichlet's test and the same Abelian theorem.

Comment: Great job! I didn't do the derivation the proper way myself, because I'm a physicist, and for me handwaving is usually good enough, especially if the result coincides with the numerical value. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I think "handwaving" is great and extremely useful. Speaking of which - do you have any intuition for the general odd dimensional case? Do you think the result will be $(\pi/2)^n/2$ in all odd dimensions? The simplex trick here works only for $n=3$ unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

A lengthy method, but it works. First, we rewrite:

$$\sin(x+y) \sin(y+z) \sin(z+x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sin(2x)+\sin(2y)+\sin(2z)-\sin(2(x+y+z)) \right)$$

Now let's change the variables (keeping the same letters for simplicity):

$$x \to \frac{1}{2}x^2, \qquad y \to \frac{1}{2}y^2, \qquad z \to \frac{1}{2}z^2$$

$$I= 2 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x y z dx dy dz}{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)} \left(\sin(x^2)+\sin(y^2)+\sin(z^2)-\sin(x^2+y^2+z^2) \right)$$

Now we introduce spherical coordinates:

$$x= r \sin \theta \cos \phi, \qquad y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi, \qquad z= r \cos \theta$$

The limits are obvious:

$$I= 2 \int_0^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{r^5 \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \phi dr d \theta d \phi}{r^6 \sin^2 \theta (\sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi+\cos^2 \theta)(\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi+\cos^2 \theta)} \times \\ \times \left(\sin(r^2 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi)+\sin(r^2 \sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi)+\sin(r^2 \cos^2 \theta)-\sin(r^2) \right)$$

Simplifying and using:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a^2 r^2) dr}{r}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

We obtain:

$$I= \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \phi d \theta d \phi}{(\sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi+\cos^2 \theta)(\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi+\cos^2 \theta)}=\pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin 2 \theta \sin 2 \phi d \theta d \phi}{4 \cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 2 \phi \sin^4 \theta}$$

Changing the variables:

$$2 \theta \to \theta, \qquad 2 \phi \to \phi$$

$$I= \pi \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin \theta \sin \phi d \theta d \phi}{8 (1+\cos \theta)+\sin^2 \phi (1-\cos \theta)^2}$$

Substituting:

$$u= \cos \theta, \qquad v = \cos \phi$$

$$I= \pi \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d u d v}{8 (1+u)+(1-v^2) (1-u)^2}$$

Substituting:

$$1-u= t$$

$$I= \pi \int_0^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d v d t}{(t-4)^2-t^2 v^2}=\pi \int_0^2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d v d t}{(t-4-tv)(t-4+tv)}$$

Taking the elementary integral w.r.t. $v$, we have:

$$I= \pi \int_0^2 \frac{dt}{t(t-4)} \ln \left(1-\frac{t}{2} \right)$$

Substituting:

$$t= 2s$$

$$I= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln (1-s) ds}{s(s-2)}=\frac{\pi}{4} \left( \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln (1-s) ds}{s-2} -\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln (1-s) ds}{s}\right)$$

> $$I=\frac{\pi}{4} \left( \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{16}$$

The last two logarithmic integrals are well known, and their values can be determined by various methods, for example the series expansion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is a complete solution. Changing to spherical coordinates changes the domain of integration, and one would have to show the limits for a growing ball and box are the same.

Comment: @heiner, why wouldn't they be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the two limits are the same, but my conviction doesn't substitute a proof. The integral is improper, the integrand not in $L_1$. Such functions can have funny behaviors, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972813/when-is-the-improper-integral-well-defined-in-multiple-dimensions. BTW, if a change like you make it is valid, going to the $L_1$ sphere aka standard simplex instead of the euclidean sphere simplifies the calculation.

Comment: I have posted an answer that shows the limits are the same, and computes it on the standard simplex.