# When is the improper integral well-defined in multiple dimensions?

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Hartman and Mikusinski's book "The Theory of Lebesgue Measure and Integration" make an interesting [remark](https://books.google.com/books?id=WcPSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA159&dq=generalized%20improper%20integral&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q&f=false) on improper integrals in multiple dimensions:

> In the case of one variable, we introduced, besides the concept of the Lebesgue integral on an infinite interval, the further concept of an improper integral.  A similar generalization does not emerge for integrals of functions of two variables.  For, if we assume only the existence of $(6)$, and do not assume the existence of $(5)$, then limits $(6)$ can have different values for different sequences $U_n$, e.g. they may have one value for the sequence of circles $x^2+y^2<n^2$ and another for the sequence of squares $|x| < n, |y| < n$. Because of this situation, the value of the integral would be undefined. If, however, we make the additional assumption that limits $(6)$ have the same value for all increasing nested sequences ${U_n}$ with union $P$, then the existence of limit $(5)$ would already follow from this and we would not obtain any generalization.

Here $(5)$ refers to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\int_{U_n}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ and $(6)$ refers to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\int_{U_n}f(x,y)dxdy$ where $(U_n)$ is an increasing sequence of bounded measurable sets whose union is an unbounded measurable set $P$.

My question is, what is the proof of the two assertions that Hartmann and Mikusinski make in the quote above? First of all, what is an example of a function $f(x,y)$ such that the integral of $f$ over the disc $x^2+y^2<n^2$ and the integral of $f(x,y)$ over the square $|x| < n, |y| < n$ converge to different values as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Second of all, how do you prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\int_{U_n}f(x,y)dxdy$ has the same value for every increasing sequence of bounded measurable sets $(U_n)$ whose union is $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\int_{U_n}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ exists (i.e. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: This question is really important for electrodynamics (physics). In a few different sections of a textbook, you'll have a closed surface integral over a vector field, but then he considers what happens when the closed surface is over all space. Then the author makes some physics remarks, very non-rigorous mathematics, and ends up claiming the improper integral is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your second question. So we assume that the integral satisfies the property on the limits that you stated.

Consider the functions $f^+$ and $f^-$, we know that
$|f|=f^++f^-$. If $|f|$ is not Lebesgue integrable, it means that either $\int f^+d\mu=+\infty $ or $\int f^-d\mu =+\infty$.

Moreover, if one is infinite and the other is finite, then it is easy to see that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{A_k}fd\mu=\int fd\mu\in\{+\infty,-\infty\},$$ for any increasing sequence of bounded measurable sets $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$.

So we must have that
$$
\int f^+d\mu=\int f^-d\mu =+\infty.
$$
Consider $E=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$ and put: $F=E^c$, $E_n=B(0,n)\cap E$ and $F_n=B(0,n)\cap F$. Fix $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. We define $A_1=E_1$, and then, for each $k> 1$, we define $A_k$ to be 
$$\mbox{the union of $A_{k-1}$ with the least indexed remaining set of the family $\{E_n\}$, if $\int_{A_{k-1}}fd\mu<\alpha$;}\\
\mbox{the union of $A_{k-1}$ with the least indexed remaining set of the family $\{F_n\}$, if $\int_{A_{k-1}}fd\mu\geq\alpha$.}
$$
Then certainly $(A_k)$ is a sequence of bounded measurable sets such that the union is $\mathbb R^2$ and the sequence $\int_{A_k} fd\mu$ "osciles around $\alpha$", since it increases if $\int_{A_k} fd\mu<\alpha$ and decreases if $\int_{A_k} fd\mu\geq \alpha$. More precisely, we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n} fd\mu = \int f^+d\mu = +\infty\ \ \mbox{ and }\ \ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{F_n} fd\mu = -\int f^-d\mu = -\infty,
$$
(this is an immediate consequence of the monotone convergence theorem).

Therefore, the sequence $\int_{A_k} f d\mu$ will have infinite elements greater than $\alpha$ and infinite elements less than $\alpha$. This also ensures that every set of the families $\{E_n\}$ and $\{F_n\}$ is picked by the sequence $A_k$.

By hypothesis, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{A_k}fd\mu$ must exist and, since $f$ "osciles around $\alpha$", we must have $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{A_k}fd\mu=\alpha$.

But since $\alpha$ was arbitrarily chosen, it contradicts our assumption on the uniqueness of the limits $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{A_k}fd\mu=\alpha$.

Comment: By the way, why doesn’t this proof carry over into the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Also, what if you require the $U_n$'s to be connected?

Comment: This proof is valid for any $\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: I don't know what happens if you require the sets to be connected.

Comment: Wait, so this is equally valid for functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and functions on $\mathbb{R}$?  Then why does the quote in my question contrast the one-dimensional case and the two-dimensional case?

Comment: I guess that in the one-dimensional case it is sufficient to require just the existence of the limits (6), and for the multi-dimensional case this is not sufficient, and one way around this is to require not only that the limits (6) exists but also that they have the same value. This assumption is stronger than the first one (it includes the first one), so it implies the existence of (5) including in the one-dimensional case. But in the one-dimensional case the first assumption is sufficient.

Comment: But I don't know exactly if/why only the existence of the limits (6) is sufficient to have the improper integral in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: How did they introduce improper integrals in the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Here is how they introduce improper integrals in one dimension: https://books.google.com/books?id=WcPSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA159&dq=generalized%20improper%20integral&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. It has to do with ordered sums. In the one-dimensional case the integral (5) may not exist but we still can define the integral to be the limit (6) with if it exists for any sequence of the form $U_n=[a_n, b_n]$, where $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to+\infty$. So, when we fix this class of $U_n$, we are imposing an order that guarantees the convergence of the integrals $\int_{U_n}fd\mu$. This limit on the nested increasing sequence $U_n$, if we disjoint the $U_n$'s, the integral of f can be viewed as an infinite sum but we can't put any order on that.

Comment: Just a few amount of orders induced by the requirement $U_n=[a_n,b_n]$. The example they gave of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ illustrates it well. It is not Lebesgue integrable but there exists the improper integral if we fix the class of $U_n$ to be this one.

Comment: So then what's the difference in the two-dimensional case?

Comment: I don't know if there is an usual way to introduce improper integrals in the two-dimensional case by fixing a particular class of coverings $(U_n)$ of bounded sets (not that big as all the coverings $(U_n)$ of bounded measurable sets). At least not as usual as the one for $\mathbb R$. They said that it could be for the class of coverings by discs centered at $0$ or cubes centered at $0$. But they would get different values, so we must pick one. I'm not completely sure about this, but I guess there is no classical/canonical preference between these two.